# Mobile hotspot is disabled on my Dell XPS 15

Tags: wireless-networking

Maybe the Killer network adapter or the driver does not support the "hosted network" feature? I just want to make sure I got everything right.

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>netsh wlan show drivers

Interface name: Wi-Fi

    Driver                    : Killer Wireless-n/a/ac 1535 Wireless Network Adapter
    Vendor                    : Qualcomm Atheros Communications Inc.
    Provider                  : Qualcomm Atheros Communications Inc.
    Date                      : 2/28/2018
    Version                   : 12.0.0.468
    INF file                  : oem25.inf
    Type                      : Native Wi-Fi Driver
    Radio types supported     : 802.11b 802.11a 802.11g 802.11n 802.11ac
    FIPS 140-2 mode supported : Yes
    802.11w Management Frame Protection supported : Yes
    Hosted network supported  : No
    Authentication and cipher supported in infrastructure mode:
```

[image]

## Update

Here's my Wireless network adapter properties page in **Device Manager**.

[image]

Comment: Native wifi driver means you are using a windows driver... Have you tried manufacturer specific drivers for your card?

Comment: turns out a restart fixed this issue...thx Windows :(

Answer (score -1):

try this way:

1. open **Device Manager**.
2. Click **View** on the menu.
3. Click the **Show hidden devices option**.
4. Expand the **Network adapters**.
5. Double-click the current working network adapter.
6. Click **Advanced**.
7. Select **802.11n/g/b** in the list of Property.
8. Select **Long only** in the Value on the right side.
9. Click **OK**.
10. Then right-click the **Microsoft Hosted Network Virtual Adapter**.
11. Disable device and re-Enable the device.
12. Double-click the adapter to open the **Properties**.
13. Click **Power Management** tab.
14. Uncheck the **Allow the computer to turn off this device to save power**.
15. Click the **OK**.

17.Then try to enable the **Mobile Hotpot** again.

Comment: I am afraid my computer does not have the options you mentioned. Any idea?

Comment: It's not going to have it. He's trying to get you to change the pre-amble settings of the card. You **shouldn't** do this. Short preamble came after wireless-b devices. Unless you have some wireless-b clients, or an Interference problem, you shouldn't change the pre-amble.